# Куда вводить данные с клавиатуры в программу Visual Sudio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Где находится окно для ввода данных программы с клавиатуры (не терминал) в Visual Studio Code?

Мне нужно отладить программу на Golang в Visual Studio Code. Я запускаю отладку клавишей F5, появляются кнопки с различными шагами, кнопки перезапуска, паузы и остановки. Нажимая F10, я дохожу до строки, в которой содержится функция считывания переменных с клавиатуры `Fscanf()`, и активными остаются только кнопки перезапуска, остановки и паузы отладки. Ничего больше не происходит, никакое окно для ввода данных не появляется. Где это окно находится?

Comment: Открываете - создаете нужный файл (язык/разметка)  - вводите - сохраняете. Какие ж тут вопросы?! Так в любом редакторе.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Где запускаете программу туда и вводите, обычно это терминал, если программа без GUI.

Comment: А на каком языке вы пишете свою программу?

Comment: Вообще если ваша программа нуждается в вводе данных пользователем без ее запуска вам не обойтись. Если вы хотите видеть что происходит с программой во время ее работы можно производить логирование и воспользоваться дебагером для платформы на которой вы создаете свою программу.

Comment: @Bleser, есть же нормальные русские слова "журналирование" и "отладчик". Зачем их коверкать на англицизмы??